# Unix cat command with output redirection metacharacter >, create empty files

Tags: file, shell, unix, io-redirection

I am using following code to create a new file **cat15** using **cat** command in UNIX

```
# cat > cat15
```

this command adds a new file **cat15** in root directory and whatever I type after this command is being stored into the file created. But I am not able to exit from this editor.

In other word, I am not getting Shell prompt symbol **#**

Comment: Press `ctrl+d` at an empty line to send an EOF character.

Comment: Arguably, this is more a question about correctly using one's terminal than about programming, and thus it may be better placed on SuperUser.

Comment: You can also do `cp /dev/null empty-file`

Answer (score 1):

The `cat` command reads from STDIN if you don't specify a filename.  It continues to do this until it receives an EOF or is killed.  You can send an EOF and get your terminal back by typing `<ctrl>+d`.

What people generally do is to either use

```
touch filename
```

or

```
echo -n > filename
```

to create an empty file.  As Charles correctly notes below, "echo -n" is not always a good idea (though you can usually count on it under "popular" Linux distros); I'd strongly suggest just using touch.

Comment: I'd suggest `printf` over `echo -n` -- more portable; not all versions of echo take flags, and the baseline POSIX standard (absent XSI extensions) is somewhat ambiguously written as to just what the flags mean.

Comment: I was hesitant to suggest "echo" for exactly that reason, but it's so darned common, I couldn't help myself. ;)  My main issue with printf is that it's often not a shell builtin, so it's super slow if this is done in a large loop.

Comment: True -- while POSIX specifies printf to exist, it's not forced to be a builtin. On the other hand, it _is_ built-in almost everywhere -- ash, busybox, etc.

Comment: `touch filename` and `echo -n > filename` behave differently if `filename` already exists. `touch` creates a file if it doesn't already exists, or updates its timestamp if it does.

Comment: I blame HP-UX for making me avoid using printf in the shell. ;)

Comment: @KeithThompson - the question specified creating a new file.  In the prescribed situation, they behave identically. :)

Comment: @dannysauer: Which is why I didn't say your answer is wrong -- but the OP should be aware of the difference.

Comment: A simpler way to create an empty file using redirection is with the `:` builtin: `: > filename` (tested on `bash`, `dash`, `ksh`, `zsh`, `tcsh`). Would love to hear if there are shells where this does NOT work.
With the exception of `zsh`, the shells mentioned support an even simpler approach: just use the redirection by itself, no command needed: `> filename`.

Comment: @mklement0: That should work in any POSIX-compliant shell, as colon is defined as a "special built-in utility".  It does require the use of the shift key, though, and you know how command-line people hate using the shift key. ;)

Comment: @dannysauer: I LOVE USING THE SHIFT KEY.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to create an empty file, regardless of whether one existed or not, you can just use ">" like this:

```
> cat15
```

It will clobber anything that already exists by that name.

Comment: Nice - while it works in most shells, it does not in `zsh`, for instance (starts waiting for stdin input). What works there as well is to use the `:` builtin: `: > cat15`. Haven't found a shell yet where that doesn't work, but that doesn't mean there aren't any (tried `bash`, `dash`, `ksh`, `zsh`, `tcsh`).